# maximum distance of point on $k$ -sphere

Tags: geometry

How can we get $k^2$ points on $k$-dimensional hypersphere such that each two points have max euclidean distance ?

Comment: Start simple and work to more complex. If this problem were asking about the 2-sphere, what would the answer be? Then consider higher dimensional spheres.

Comment: in 2- dimensional (circle ) is simple because use the point (1,0), (-1,0),(0,1),(0,-1), but in 3- dimensional I dont know  how to get  ninth point on sphere

Comment: A $k$-sphere exists in $k+1$ dimensions. So, $S^0$ is a 0-sphere, which is two points on the line ($\pm 1$). It exists in one dimension. $S^1$ is a 1-sphere, which is the standard two-dimensional circle. This is an important distinction because $S^1$, to place one point, you merely choose one point. That is it. Any point will work, because you want $1^2$ points, which will be 1.  For the 2-sphere ($S^2$), it is the sphere in three dimensions. Choose any point. Now, you will want three additional points. Basically, you are inscribing a tetrahedron inside the 2-sphere with maximal volume.

Comment: Similarly for the $k$-sphere, my intuition says that you will be inscribing the $k+1$-simplex of maximal volume. So, you choose a base point and then every other point you choose will be fixed up to rotations.

Comment: I have mistake, i like to find $k^2$ points on $k-1$ -dimensional hypersphere for example in 3-dimensional on sphere i like to find 9 points with this property

Comment: Consider the circle example you gave. The distance between (1,0) and (-1,0) is 2. The distance between (1,0) and (0,1) is $\sqrt{2}$. This is not max. Max is a distance of 2. So, in what way is your solution the correct solution?

Comment: because for each another 4 points on circle  the distance of each two points  is  less then this four points

Comment: Be careful with the wording of questions like this. The way you worded it is ambiguous. You are not looking for pairwise maximums, but maximums across a set. You are basically looking for a formula to find the vertices of a regular convex polyhedra. Note that there are only five such solids, making it unclear if it is possible to find $k^2$ such points. Have you proven it is even possible? I wonder if you can show that there exists an infinite sequence of positions, each one increasing the distance between at least two points in the system, but such that there is no way to generate a limit set

Comment: you say we  cant  find some points such that $ \min _{x,y} d(x,y)$  is max ?

Comment: I know have Platonic solid I do not want to be regular shape. i like have max distance .

Comment: I do not say you cannot find some points such that $\text{min}_{x,y}d(x,y)$ is max. I asked if you have proven that such a set of points exists? I am dubious.