How many vectors can be placed in $n$ dimensions given max cosine similarity?
In machine learning we usually use the concept of cosine similarity to compare things. Similar things should have embeddings with high cosine similarity and different things should have embeddings with low cosine similarity. Let’s say we have a threshold of similarity $x$, that is, two things are similar iff their embedding’s cosine similarity is $\geq x$.
I was wondering how many categories a $n$ dimensional embedding space could encode. A first approach would be to choose some $x$ and find how many vectors we can place in a $n$ dimensional space such that the cosine similarity between any pair of vectors is $<x$. Each vector could be thought as the “center” of a different category and an input to that model that belongs to a certain category would be close to its vector.
For $x=\cos(60^\circ)=\frac{1}{2}$ the problem gets reduced to the kissing number problem. For $x=cos(90°)=0$ all the vectors must be orthogonal and I am pretty confident the answer is $2n$ (two opposite vectors in each axis). For $x<0$ I believe you can have only $2$ vectors.
Main question is: How many vectors I can place in $n$ dim space such that each pair of vectors has cosine similarity less than $x$?
I know there is no general formula (otherwise the kissing number problem would be solved) but I wonder if there are any results on this, such as lower bound, etc.

Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279544/return-an-array-of-evenly-distributed-points-on-a-sphere-give-radius-and-origin?noredirect=1, and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2867211/maximum-distance-of-point-on-k-sphere?noredirect=1 if you are interested in higher dimensions.  If you search for points on a sphere in Approach0 you will find many more.
